# Searchview not working inside toolbar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-toolbar, searchbar

Searchbar is responding(not visible), when i click the search icon inside the toolbar
menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

searchable.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="search_hint" />
```

manifestfile

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SearchbarActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- This metadata entry provides further configuration details for searches -->
        <!-- that are handled by this activity. -->

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
```

searchbaractivity

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_search, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)
            getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();



    return true;
}
```

v21/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">false</item>
</style>
```

styles.xml

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>

</style>
```

I have extended AppCompatActivity.I have tried the same code earlier and i got it working, after that i made changes inside styles.xml and v21/styles.xml,I think this made made the problem. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code 
and implements `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`

do other operations according to your requirements( if you get the solution , please mark it as accepted answer, even you can ask more help related to same)

```
    SearchView searchView =  (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    int searchImgId = android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button;
    ImageView v = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

Comment: Hey,thanks for the reply.I  tried the above code, its not working.Once check the styles.xml and v21/styles.xml.I think there is a problem in Toolbar or Theme.

Comment: why are you using <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />  try the code after removing it from manifest.xml

Comment: tell me the error message or Log message so that I can help you with the same ? what happens when you click on search icon of Menu?

Comment: Actually the app is not crashing and no error, the searchbar which comes inside toolbar, is not coming

Answer (score 0):

Remove `collapseActionView` from show as action.
Just add     `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

Comment: Hey,thanks for the reply.I  tried  ifroom and always, its not working.Once check the styles.xml and v21/styles.xml.I think there is a problem in Toolbar or Theme.